# Как вывести в DataGridView данные из таблицы в SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

В SQL Server в базе данных Test есть таблица test:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
  [Key] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [Value] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Надо с помощью EF Code First вывести данные из test в DataGridView. Редактировать и сохранять данные в базе данных не нужно, только вывести в контрол.
Какой минимальный и достаточный код нужен для этого?

Answer (score 2):

К WinForms проекту надо подключить nuget-пакет [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework).

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var cs = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Test;";
        var dc = new DbContext(cs);
        var dt = dc.Database.SqlQuery<Test>("select * from test");
        var f = new Form();
        var dg = new DataGridView() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        dg.DataSource = dt.ToList();
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
    class Test {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```