# ADO.NET. Как создать модель из результата SQL запроса

Tags: c#, ado.net

Допустим есть класс Model с полями, соответствующими названиям полей в таблице. Я хочу сделать функцию, для получения этой модели из резулатата SQL запроса, примерно такого вида:

```
Model model = DataBase.FindByPrimaryKey<Model>(modelID);
```

Как сделать такую функцию?

Comment: энным количеством способов, самым простым из которых будет использование ORM, например, Entity Framework

Comment: Желательно бы простое самописное, т.к. мне кроме выборки по ID больше ничего не надо

Comment: данные из sql server надо десериализовать, для работы с бд используют EF. посмотрите пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477795/#477796)

Comment: @DimaGvozdev если вам нужно "самое простое", то самописные варианты будут сложнее в реализации, чем использование ORM - там слишком много придется писать руками, не забывая также проверять корректность данных и тд, тогда как ORM всё сделает за вас.  Если вам тем не менее нужно что-то самописное, то копайте в торону IDataReader/DataTable/DataSet. Данные оттуда, как было замечено выше, придется получать руками

Comment: еще один пример использования EF - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477703/#477704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще всего, мне нужно считать данные и потом вернуть их в виде JSON объекта из WebApi метода. Следующий фрагмент выполняет SQL statement (можно использовать STORED PROSEDURE добавив `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`) и читает результаты в `List<dynamic>`. **Поэтому нет необходимости создавать Model в коде C#**. Я хотел лишь объяснить основную идею на примере ниже. Понятно, что для поиска по id можно использовать `CommandBehavior.SingleRow` и упростить код получив `dynamic` вместо `List<dynamic>`, но по сути код оснается следующим:

```
var returnObject = new List<dynamic>();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DB)) {
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE id=@id";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 1 });

        if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            cmd.Connection.Open();

        var retObject = new List<dynamic>();
        using (var dataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
            while (await dataReader.ReadAsync()) {
                var dataRow = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                for (var iFiled = 0; iFiled < dataReader.FieldCount; iFiled++) {
                    // dataRow.Add из следующий строки можно заменить но
                    //   if (dataReader.IsDBNull(iFiled))
                    //       dataRow.Add(dataReader.GetName(iFiled), dataReader[iFiled]);
                    // если возвращенный NULL предпочтительно не
                    // сохранять вообще в dataRow
                    dataRow.Add(
                        dataReader.GetName(iFiled),
                        dataReader.IsDBNull(iFiled) ? null : dataReader[iFiled] // использовать null вмесно {}
                    );
                }

                retObject.Add((ExpandoObject)dataRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я думаю, что этот код нетрудно адаптировать под ваши нужды и сохранять результат в fileds или properties модели вмесно `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

EF - тяжелый для такой задачи, но Dapper как раз для ADO.NET

Comment: За что минус???

Comment: _"За что минус?"_ -- минус не мой. а у меня вопрос: EntityFramework.dll - 4.95 MB, а у Dapper сколько? Dapper может тоже самое что и EF? есть Code First?

Comment: @cpp_user есть подозрение, что минус за то, что это скорее не ответ, а комментарий. Добавьте ссылку, код, и станет похоже на ответ.

Comment: @Stack а ему и не нужно этого уметь. Он делает свою небольшую задачу и делает ее очень быстро. А cpp_user как раз и говорит, что для такой задачи, которую обозначил автор вопроса, его вполне достаточно.

Comment: Dapper не замена EF, а дополнение для тех кто работает напрямую с запросами или хранимыми процедурами через ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

> мне кроме выборки по ID больше ничего не надо

В такой ситуации, наверное проще всего использовать DataTable и SqlDataAdapter

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var a = new SqlDataAdapter("select id from [test]", connectionString);
var d = new DataTable();
a.Fill(d);  // загрузка данных из sql server

var ids = d.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => (int)r["id"]).ToList();
```