# Как сделать простейший клиент для базы данных MSSQLS Express в Windows Forms приложении на C#

Tags: c#

Сейчас я только понял как добавить в источники данных БД. Дальше не могу понять, как поступить дальше. Я хочу вывести информацию из БД в DataGridView. [image: Добавил источник даных]

Comment: А вы пытались понять сами? Где ваши размышления, где код?

Comment: Я погуглил, но не понял принципов никаких. Код пока пустой

Comment: Первая [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477703/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-datagridview-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-sql-server) в гугле.